# display karma tests on browser

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm new to karma unit-testing angular. I tested angular-socket-io application. This is what I saw when I ran karma start on the console.

```
21:58 /tmp/angular-socket-io $ karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9999/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.8.3)]: Connected on socket AOee3c4IW51Z30jfShdU
Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.8.3): Executed 18 of 18 SUCCESS (4.393 secs / 0.083 secs)
INFO [Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.8.3)]: Connected on socket IMCGlDXZwhJJ8Y6YShdV
Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.8.3): Executed 18 of 18 SUCCESS (0.159 secs / 0.09 secs)
Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.8.3): Executed 18 of 18 SUCCESS (0.249 secs / 0.093 secs)
TOTAL: 36 SUCCESS
```

I would like to see all tests listed on my Chrome browser. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would be happy with opening an HTML report that Karma generated for you, then take a look at [karma-html-reporter](https://github.com/dtabuenc/karma-html-reporter). Just add it to the reporters list in your Karma configuration:

```
{
  // much more before this

  reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

  // the default configuration
  htmlReporter: {
    outputDir: 'karma_html', // where to put the reports 
    templatePath: null, // set if you moved jasmine_template.html
    focusOnFailures: true, // reports show failures on start
    namedFiles: false, // name files instead of creating sub-directories
    pageTitle: null, // page title for reports; browser info by default
    urlFriendlyName: false // simply replaces spaces with _ for files/dirs

    // experimental
    preserveDescribeNesting: false, // folded suites stay folded 
    foldAll: false, // reports start folded (only with preserveDescribeNesting)
  }

  // much more after this
}
```